# Swift: How to return a value from asynchronous operation?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift3, vk

I'm creating a social network app using SwiftyVK and SwiftyJSON frameworks. There is a function which sends a post with attached photos. Let's call it sendToVK(). Here is brief review of it:

```
func sendToVK(message: String, photos: [UIImage]) {
    // declaration of some vars and lets
    var attachments = "" // this var should collect all the information about 
//photos to attach, for example: "photo123456_987654,photo123456_612366,photo123456_123156",
// where 123456 is id of the user, whose wall I'm going post to (I already have it),
// numbers after "_" are id of the photo, they are contained in the server's response
// in case of successful upload

    for photo in photos {
       // I'm uploading photos in this loop, and I assume that I have to get 
       //the ID's of my photos from server's response also somewhere in this loop in order to work with them further
       //Let's say photoString is someString + photoID, for example, photoString == "photo12345_9876543"
       var photoID = ""
       //the following function is uploading photos asynchronously. 
       //It is also responsible for getting IDs from server's response
       VK.API.Upload.Photo.toWall.toUser(media, userId: userIDForVK).send(
       onSuccess: { response in
         print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto success \n \(response)")
         photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue }, //this is SwiftyJSON syntax
       onError: { error in
         print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto fail \n \(error)") },
       onProgress: { done, total in
         print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto progress: \(done) of \(total))") }
       )
       photoString = something + photoID //by this moment photoID is empty, that's the problem! (see explanation below)
       attachments += photoString
    }

    //At this moment I must have all the neccessary parameters
    //in the var wallPostParameters, including attachments!
    VK.API.Wall.post(wallPostParameters).send(
            onSuccess: {response in print(response)},
            onError: {error in print(error)},
            onProgress: {done, total in print(" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! send \(done) of \(total)")}
        )
}
```

So the exact problem is, inside the loop the uploading task is being dispatched to another thread, and respectively the server's response is coming somewhere else at another time. And in fact, by the moment I need my **attachments** string to be filled with **photoString**s (right before the call to VK.API.Wall.post()), it actually has the form, for example, "photo123456_,photo123456_,photo123456_", i.e. without photo IDs, because these photos have not been uploaded in the other thread yet, thus these IDs were not added to **attachments**.

And the question is, how can I implement in Swift that in each iteration of the loop we are not proceeding but waiting until the photo will be uploaded, adding its id to **photoString** to collect these **photoString**s in **attachments**, so before the call to VK.API.Wall.post() everything would be ready to go?

Comment: If you have the number of photo to upload, just make another var outside the loop, +1 on each `onSuccess` and compare it with the number of photos to upload then only execute the code, the code also should be place in the closure call back

Comment: @Tj3n and how can I prevent the following code from executing in Swift?

Comment: answer below look good :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read an article about GCD in Swift, and my final solution is:

```
private static func sendToVK(_ message: String, photos: [UIImage], userIDForVK: String) {
        var wallPostParameters = Dictionary<VK.Arg, String>()
        wallPostParameters[VK.Arg.message] = message
        var attachments = ""
        var successfulUploadsCount = 0

        let sendPostWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
            VK.API.Wall.post(wallPostParameters).send(
            onSuccess: {response in print(response)},
            onError: {error in print(error)},
            onProgress: {done, total in print("\n send \(done) of \(total)\n")} )
        }

        for photo in photos {
            let media = Media(imageData: Data(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 1.0)!), type: Media.ImageType.JPG)

            VK.API.Upload.Photo.toWall.toUser(media, userId: userIDForVK).send(

                onSuccess: { response in
                    let photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue
                    let photoString = "photo" + userIDForVK + "_" + photoID

                    if attachments.isEmpty {
                        attachments = photoString
                    } else {
                        attachments += "," + photoString
                    }
                    successfulUploadsCount += 1

                    if successfulUploadsCount == photos.count {
                        wallPostParameters[VK.Arg.attachments] = attachments
                        sendPostWorkItem.perform()
                    }
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto success \n \(response)\n") },

                onError: { error in
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto fail \n \(error)\n") },

                onProgress: { done, total in
                    print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto progress: \(done) of \(total))\n") } )
        }

        if photos.isEmpty {
            sendPostWorkItem.perform()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work in your case

```
func sendToVK(message: String, photos: [UIImage]) {

    var attachments = "" 
    var photosUploaded = 0

    for photo in photos {


       var photoID = ""
       VK.API.Upload.Photo.toWall.toUser(media, userId: userIDForVK).send(
       onSuccess: { response in
    photosUploaded += 1
         photoID = response[0,"id"].stringValue
photoString = something + photoID 
        attachments += photoString

if photosUploaded == photos.count {

    VK.API.Wall.post(wallPostParameters).send(
            onSuccess: {response in print(response)},
            onError: {error in print(error)},
            onProgress: {done, total in print(" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! send \(done) of \(total)")}
        )
} 

    }, //this is SwiftyJSON syntax
       onError: { error in
         print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto fail \n \(error)") },
       onProgress: { done, total in
         print("\n SwiftyVK: uploadPhoto progress: \(done) of \(total))") }
       )

    }


}
```